# How to infer avro schema from a kafka topic in Apache Beam KafkaIO

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam, confluent-schema-registry, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-kafkaio

I'm using Apache Beam's kafkaIO to read from a topic that has an avro schema in Confluent schema registry.
I'm able to deserialize the message and write to files. But ultimately i want to write to BigQuery. My pipeline isn't able to infer the schema.
How do I extract/infer the schema and attach it to the data in the pipeline so that my downstream processes (write to BigQuery) can infer the schema?

Here is the code where I use the schema registry url to set the deserializer and where i read from Kafka:

```
    consumerConfig.put(
                        AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, 
                        options.getSchemaRegistryUrl());

String schemaUrl = options.getSchemaRegistryUrl().get();
String subj = options.getSubject().get();

ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider<GenericRecord> valDeserializerProvider =
            ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider.of(schemaUrl, subj);

pipeline
        .apply("Read from Kafka",
                KafkaIO
                        .<byte[], GenericRecord>read()
                        .withBootstrapServers(options.getKafkaBrokers().get())
                        .withTopics(Utils.getListFromString(options.getKafkaTopics()))
                        .withConsumerConfigUpdates(consumerConfig)
                        .withValueDeserializer(valDeserializerProvider)
                        .withKeyDeserializer(ByteArrayDeserializer.class)

                        .commitOffsetsInFinalize()
                        .withoutMetadata()

        );
```

I initially thought that this would be enough for beam to infer the schema, but it does not since hasSchema() returns false.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a working solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is [ongoing work](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/10978) to support inferring of Avro schema, stored in Confluent Schema Registry, in `KafkaIO`. Though, it's possible to do now in user pipeline code as well.

Comment: thanks for the reply. How would i go about it? Getting the schema with an http call and using AvroIO to set the schema?

Comment: I answered in a separate response.

Answer (score 0):

This code probably will work but I have not tested yet.

```
// Fetch Avro schema from CSR
SchemaRegistryClient registryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient("schema_registry_url", 10);
SchemaMetadata latestSchemaMetadata = registryClient.getLatestSchemaMetadata("schema_name");
Schema avroSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(latestSchemaMetadata.getSchema());

PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);


// Create KafkaIO.Read with Avro schema deserializer
KafkaIO.Read<String, GenericRecord> read = KafkaIO.<String, GenericRecord>read()
    .withBootstrapServers("host:port")
    .withTopic("topic_name")
    .withConsumerConfigUpdates(ImmutableMap.of("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl))
    .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
    .withValueDeserializerAndCoder((Class) KafkaAvroDeserializer.class, AvroCoder.of(avroSchema));

// Apply Kafka.Read and set Beam schema based on Avro Schema
p.apply(read)
 .apply(Values.<GenericRecord>create()).setSchema(schema,
    AvroUtils.getToRowFunction(GenericRecord.class, avroSchema),
    AvroUtils.getFromRowFunction(GenericRecord.class))
```

Then I think you can use `BigQueryIO.Write` with `useBeamSchema()`.

Comment: thanks for this! 

i tried using `.withValueDeserializerAndCoder((Class<? extends Deserializer<GenericRecord>>) KafkaAvroDeserializer.class, AvroCoder.of(avroSchema))`, but that doesn't work, so I tried calling withValueDeserializer and setCoder separately:

`.setSchema(AvroUtils.toBeamSchema(avroSchema), TypeDescriptor.of(GenericRecord.class),
                AvroUtils.getToRowFunction(GenericRecord.class, avroSchema),
                AvroUtils.getFromRowFunction(GenericRecord.class))
                .setCoder(AvroCoder.of(avroSchema))`

which gave me the same error